# Is it possible to fail Cold Call Killer?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm getting pretty close to being able to trace the call for the sidequest Cold Call Killer. However, I was wondering if it was possible to fail the trace? It seems like there is ample opportunity to miss tracing the call, especially if you don't move your cursor. I found out that you get a game over and have to retry if you miss getting to one of the ringing phones.

What happens when you fail to trace the call? Will the entire sidequest fail, or will you get another chance to trace it?

Comment: I'm wondering if you just get enough calls to the point where you can't fail...I've noticed that whenever you reach the destination phone, some of the progress bar gets filled in even before you start tracing.

Comment: Good question. I would assume at some point, the killer is going to run out of things to say, but don't know for sure.

Comment: @DoozerBlake I finished the trace very early into the last call and although I got the location the screen stayed up and let me listen to the rest of his story, so there is a certain number of story parts. Not sure if you can fail the whole thing, though, would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, finally tried it: if you don't get enough progress on the trace, you will trigger a game over. You'll have to restart from Zsasz sending you running for the payphone, in much the same way as if you don't pick up the second payphone before it stops ringing.

Comment: So even if you're a few calls into the mission, you'll have to start from the beginning?

Comment: No, you start from the most recent call. Will edit into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think I may have failed it. :/
In my stupidity I didn't realize that you actually have to MOVE the cursor around to trace the calls - I only figured this out on maybe the third call. It really looks like he's not interested in playing his game any more.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How many calls have you answered?

Answer (score 1):

I beat this mission without ever moving the cursor for the trace during any of the phone calls. The trace was at 14% during the 6th or so phone call and the game just gave me the "Oh! You found his lair" quest marker.

Comment: Quite defiant, eh?